Validator commission rates before epoch 202
I am trying to see if there's a way to get the commission rates of a validator before epoch 202.  I'm wondering if this calculation was added in a release around this time.
The odd thing if it was a release is that epoch 201 gives null for commission, epoch 202 gives a value, then epoch 203 gives null again.  204+ all give the correct value for commission.
Example RPC call to getInflationReward on an old validator that was alive pre-epoch 202.
curl --location 'https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "method": "getInflationReward",
    "params": [
        [
            "beefKGBWeSpHzYBHZXwp5So7wdQGX6mu4ZHCsH3uTar"
        ],
        {
            "epoch": 201
        }
    ]
}'  | jq

Commission is null :
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "result": [
    {
      "amount": 461280375727,
      "commission": null,
      "effectiveSlot": 87264000,
      "epoch": 201,
      "postBalance": 2303678884416
    }
  ],
  "id": 1
}


Unfortunately, it looks like the commission recording was only added at that point. Here's the original PR: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/pull/18585
This means the data isn't present before that. You would need to parse out earlier transactions to the vote program to figure out how commissions were set and updated.
